# Images in React: is it possible to use a string from an imported object as the source path for an image?

Tags: image, reactjs

Question about using images in React!

Importing a pic and then using it works:

```
import photo from "../img/profilephoto.jpg"

<img src={photo} />
```

Using props as the source inside a require() works:

```
<img src={require(`../img/${this.props.img}`)} />
```

But importing an object (with more objects), and then using navigation to get a string, does not work!

```
import text from "../text" // This is the object which contains more objects

<img src={require(`../img/${text.contact.photo}`)} />
```

Error because "text is not defined".

I've looking for answer on the internet, but I can't find a solution for an imported object. Is it possible to use a key/value in an imported object as a path source for an img, where the img itself is not previously imported?

Comment: you need the index of the src

Comment: Did you put `module.exports` in `text` file? add `text` file code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved!

**Before**

I had it like this in text.js; just objects:

```
export default {

  header: {
    key: "value,
    key: "value",
    photo: "./img/photo.jpg"
},

  footer: {
  ...and so on...
  }

}
```

And in the component i had this:

```
import text from "../text" // This is the object wich contains more objects

<img src={require(`../img/${text.contact.photo}`)} />
```

**After**

In order for the require() to work, the photo needs to be known. So I changed to this in the text.js:

```
*import photo from "./img/photo.jpg"* //This import is new

export default {

  header: {
    key: "value,
    key: "value",
    photo: *photo* //Use the imported phto instead of writing the file path
},

  footer: {
  ...and so on...
  }

}
```

And in the component:

```
<img src={text.contact.photo}/> //Using the text.js with the objects
```

And now it works!!

Thanx for feedback!